# How to fix a git merge that was stopped in between with an interrupt?

Tags: git, git-merge

I was modifying a couple of files. Then I tried to push the code into the repository. For this I used the following commands:

```
git add <FILENAME1>
git commit -m "explanation of merge"
git pull
```

At this point the pull failed with the message:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>
> (FILENAME2).
>
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

So I tried the following command:

```
git checkout FILENAME2
git pull
```

However, at this point the git pull became stuck. I now realize that perhaps I should have run the "git commit" command again before pulling. Is that what caused git to get stuck?

I waited for like 10 minutes with nothing happening. Then I aborted this using cntrl+C. However, now I'm seeing that there is a new branch that's been created.

If earlier I was on **(branch-1)** then now I am on **(branch-1|MERGING)**.

**Can someone please explain what is going on? How do I get back to branch-1 *and* retain my filename1 at the same time?**

**Note:** running a git status shows the following:

> Changes to be committed:
>
> ```
>    modified:   FILENAME2
>
>    modified:   FILENAME1
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to find your last commit id then, you need to reset your repository at your last commit state with the following command :

```
git reset --hard commitId
```

Once you done it, you have the choice to secure your work in a separate branch with

```
git check-out -b savedBranch
git check-out branch1
```

Then your need to pull branch1 because someone pushed before you and you can merge correctly

Or else, if you don't want to create a new branch, you can simple make a rebase of your work on the pushed code with the following way

```
git rebase origin/branch1
```

This command will try to make like you've got pulled your branch before working on it

correct the conflicts then

```
git add . (Note: This will add all modified files and untracked files that's result of the rebase conflicts correction into the staging)
git rebase --continue
```

and this as many times you need it

then enjoy ! :)

I recommand you to use the tig utility for linux in command line to get a good view of your commits

Comment: Could you please provide some explanations on what we're trying to do with each of these commands? I just want to be sure before I type any commands. Also, how do I get the commitId? I stopped the commit with an interrupt right?

Comment: it's done, sorry i'm a newbie on stackoverflow and i'm not really confident in my english

Comment: Thank you for replying. This answer is too technical. I don't have much experience in git to understand git add. and git rebase.

Comment: But you made a git add to commit your work ^^". Git add is to prepare your commit, with this you're telling to git "attention, i'll commit this file", the dot select all modified and untrakeds files.

The git rebase is a little more technical yes, i tried to develop a little in my answer but you still can read the documentation ^^"
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase